# Set up spinner depends on which button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

What I want to do is change the spinner values depends on the button clicked. For example, the spinner value will be Japan, Thailand show in the 2nd activity if I clicked the Asia button. However, the spinner value did not show up after I clicked the Asia button and start 2nd activity.

This is my code in activity 1:

```
spinnerDestination=findViewById(R.id.spinnerDestination);

    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    int i=extras.getInt("asia",-1);

    if(i==2)
    {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.asia, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDestination.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

code in activity 2:

```
btn.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonAsia));
    btn.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonEurope));
    btn.add(findViewById(R.id.buttonOceanic));

    for(int i=0;i<btn.size();i++)
    {
        int j=i;
        btn.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("destination", j);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Did I miss anything or did it wrongly in the code. I'm new to android actually.